# Wall leaks due to rotten wood in footer!

Tags: concrete, leak

[image: leak]My home was built in 1979, and I have a small leak in the basement. It appears to me that the water is coming from a piece of 1x4 that is embedded in the footer, presumably this wood goes all the way thru to the outside and is now rotten and leaking. As this is the wet season, I'm trying "radonseal" to stop the leak for now, then a more proper fix this summer.  I'm thinking I can just dig out the rotten wood and patch with new concrete once things dry out.  My question is, why is this piece of wood sticking thru a basement wall in the first place?  Maybe it was intended as interior wall then they changed plan? [Basement leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P8eg.jpg)

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: That appears to be a patch - not the original foundation wall.  I'm guessing it was a lateral brace for the form and the person who put them together didn't think through how they were going to get it out after the pour.

Answer (score 1):

In the photo there is evidence of two different concrete work. The original is the curb with the 1 x 4 projecting from it and a more recent mix just above it. There is also a visible seam line on the wall which may indicate the wall was opened for some reason. In either case the board was most likely part of the concrete form that was constructed when and if the wall was repaired. My only doubt about it being form work is that it wasn't or couldn't be removed. Unless it was by the previous owner DIY-ing a wall repair.

But I'd agree with your plan to remove it and plug up the opening. If you use hydraulic cement patch you would not need to wait for the opening to dry. In fact hydraulic patch preforms better when the surrounding concrete is slightly wet. It will expand slightly so that it fills voids fairly completely.